# Angular routing path including hashes

Tags: angular, angular-router

I want to redirect some legacy AngularJS routes to new Angular components. But the path matcher is ignoring hashes:

```js
routes = [
  {
    path: 'oldurl#tab1',
    redirectTo: 'newurl/page1',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'oldurl#tab2',
    redirectTo: 'newurl/page2',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
]
```

Is there a way to match hashes in the URL?